# Hybris: How to pass class as a parameter to cms:component?

Tags: java, html, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I've started to learn Hybris and I want to find out how to pass the class as a parameter to a custom CMS Component (for the component's root element).

Let's suppose that in a jsp file named `customNavigationComponent.jsp` I have this piece of code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags"%>

<c:forEach items="${navigation.entries}" var="navigationLink">
    <div class="custom-component-wrapper">
        <cms:component component="${navigationLink.item}"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

And the custom component looks like this:

```
<a href="${component.url}">
    <div>${component.linkText}</div>
</a>
```

I would like to understand what I need to do to pass the class `navigation-link` as a parameter, like this:

```
<cms:component component="${navigationLink.item}" class="navigation-link"/>
```

so that the rendered result will be similar to:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="navigation-link">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute called, `class` in `cms:component` and therefore the following statement will not work:

```
<cms:component component="${navigationLink.item}" class="navigation-link"/>
```

Please check https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/cms2lib/cmstags/CMSComponentTag.html

In order to understand it better, you can compare it with `c:forEach`. At https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html, you will find a list of attributes available with `c:forEach` and if you want to dig deeper, you can further check https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/apidocs/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport.html

If you want to use your statement, you will need to create a custom tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arvind! I've tried adding: element="div" as a parameter to the <cms:component .../> like this: <cms:component component="${navigationLink.item}" element="div" class="navigation-link"/> and it wraps the content of my custom component in a <div> with the class "navigation-link".
Is there any way I can tweak the component rendering logic directly? If I manage to find the renderer class I can try to modify / extend it so that it adds the class directly to the root element of the custom component. Would that be possible? If the answer is yes, then what appends that wrapper?

Comment: Hi @ConstaGorgan - as you can see in the documentation (https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/cms2lib/cmstags/CMSComponentTag.html), there is only one attribute, `component` which you can set with `cms:component`. AFAIK, a tag (either custom or standard/OOTB) can not make any change into its parent element. Maybe you find something at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/819-3669/6n5sg7b50/index.html